# Burp Suite's keeps my ip safe?

Tags: webserver, anonymity, burp-suite

I am starting to learn how to use Burp Suite, but since it is kind of (tho I know it does more) automatic way of plugging information into a website/form, should I still use proxychain/vpn to keep my ip safe?

It seems my IP address would be easy to get otherwise. I tried using it to test my website but still unsure.

Answer (score 3):

Burp Suite will make requests the same way your browser does. Nothing is different. It looks automated on your side, but it's just making connections like every other application you have.

Your IP address will be at the log files of the target site.

Answer (score 1):

Burp Suite simply put is an Interception Proxy.What it does is sit between your browser and the internet and intercepts all request and responses.It in no way comes **pre-configured** to change your ip address

> Should I still use proxychain/vpn to keep my ip safe?

Yes,to ensure anonymity.